# How to run Flink word count java version example in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

Do we need to Add any dependency in the Flink interpreter?

Here is my flink interpreter flink interpreter on zeppelin:

[image]

And here is my code in Zeppelin nootbook flink java version wordcount example:

[image]

```
%flink

public class WordCountExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
            "Who's there?",
            "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?");


        text.print();
    }
}
```

(for simplification, i m simple getting text to dataset and printing it.)

I am getting this error

```
 ^
```

I have no idea, how to run on zeppelin.